# Запустить метод родителя как событие

Tags: javascript

Есть HTML разметка примерно следующего вида, включающая в себя элементы `parent` и `child`:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="child">
            Нажми меня!
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

`parent` входит в объект `obj`, наряду с другими методами и свойствами:

```
obj = {}
obj.elem = document.querySelector('.parent');
obj.prop = "123"
obj.method = function (){alert (this.prop)}
```

На child я хотел бы повесить `onclick` событие `obj.method`. Вопрос: Как в данном случае лучше всего указать на родительский объект? Единственный способ, который приходит в голову это создать в дочернем объекте свойство в котором явно сослаться на родительский объект и оттуда уже плясать.

Comment: В вопросе приведен только один объект. Что Вы имеете в виду под дочерним и родительским объектами? К которому их них относится объект `obj`?

Comment: `this.elem` будет ссылаться на родительский элемент.